# shopify return articles with same tags as current article

Tags: tags, blogs, shopify, liquid

I'm looking to create a 'Similar Articles' section which returns all articles with tags that are the same as the current article.

Here's what I have so far:

```
{% if article.tags.size > 0 %}
{% assign search_tag = {article.tags | join: ' , ' } %}
{% endif %}

    {% for article in blogs.news.articles limit:settings.sidebar_recent_artcie %}
        {% if article.tags contains {search_tag} %}
             <li><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a><br /><small>posted on {{ article.published_at | date: '%b %d, %Y' }}</small></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This works for  when the article contains 1 tag, so I guess 'Contains' can only search for the whole {search_tag} string within the list of tags.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You might want to split the search tags into an array as opposed to using the comma-delimited string, and then search the articles for the tags, doing the contains on a per word basis. If all match, you'll know. Keeping the search_tags as a string like this: "foo, buzz, bizz" and using contains on tags where they are stored as a string, but are actually an array, might be your problem here. So doing the check as follows might work better?

```
- "foo, buzz, bizz" contains "foo"?
- "foo, buzz, bizz" contains "buzz"?
- "foo, buzz, bizz" contains "bizz"?
```

Bingo?